# Unity3d server auto discover, LAN only

Tags: client-server, unity-game-engine

I need to implement a game with a server in a local network, *with no Internet access*.

Provided that I can handle the connections and network communication between clients and server if they are connected, I'd like to know if there's a elegant way to make clients discover server's address at startup.

---

I'm providing my approach as an answer, in order to share the knowledge, but it would be nice to see if there is a more elegant/automatic approach.

Comment: Alexandre, I'm pretty sure that's the only way.  It's one of those things Unity "uselessly forgot to include, that you need every time"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clients will use a specific port to connect to the game server. I implemented a UDP multicast in a different port so clients can get server's IP.

The following code is for both server and client, written in Unity Javascript. On the **server** side, it will start sending multicast messages every second at port 5100. **Clients** will listen to the same port, until they detect a new message. Then they identify sender's IP and establish a client-server connection the Unity3d way.

```
private var server_port : int = 5000;
private var server_ip : String;

// multicast
private var startup_port : int = 5100;
private var group_address : IPAddress = IPAddress.Parse ("224.0.0.224");
private var udp_client : UdpClient;
private var remote_end : IPEndPoint;

function Start ()
{
    // loaded elsewhere
    if (station_id == "GameServer")
        StartGameServer ();
    else
        StartGameClient ();
}

function StartGameServer ()
{
    // the Unity3d way to become a server
    init_status = Network.InitializeServer (10, server_port, false);
    Debug.Log ("status: " + init_status);

    StartBroadcast ();
}

function StartGameClient ()
{
    // multicast receive setup
    remote_end = IPEndPoint (IPAddress.Any, startup_port);
    udp_client = UdpClient (remote_end);
    udp_client.JoinMulticastGroup (group_address);

    // async callback for multicast
    udp_client.BeginReceive (new AsyncCallback (ServerLookup), null);

    MakeConnection ();
}

function MakeConnection ()
{
    // continues after we get server's address
    while (!server_ip)
        yield;

    while (Network.peerType == NetworkPeerType.Disconnected)
    {
        Debug.Log ("connecting: " + server_ip +":"+ server_port);

        // the Unity3d way to connect to a server
        var error : NetworkConnectionError;
        error = Network.Connect (server_ip, server_port);

        Debug.Log ("status: " + error);
        yield WaitForSeconds (1);
    }
}

/******* broadcast functions *******/
function ServerLookup (ar : IAsyncResult)
{
    // receivers package and identifies IP
    var receiveBytes = udp_client.EndReceive (ar, remote_end);

    server_ip = remote_end.Address.ToString ();
    Debug.Log ("Server: " + server_ip);
}

function StartBroadcast ()
{
    // multicast send setup
    udp_client = UdpClient ();
    udp_client.JoinMulticastGroup (group_address);
    remote_end = IPEndPoint (group_address, startup_port);

    // sends multicast
    while (true)
    {
        var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes ("GameServer");
        udp_client.Send (buffer, buffer.Length, remote_end);

        yield WaitForSeconds (1);
    }
}
```

Attaching this to your `GameObject` should do the trick.

Comment: BTW here's a nice long explanation of same ... http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/571052/networking-masterserver.html#answer-837609  Great code Alexandre

Answer (score 4):

Here is a c# version
Thanks

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

public class OwnNetworkManager : MonoBehaviour
{

private int server_port = 5000;
private string server_ip;

// multicast
private int startup_port = 5100;
private IPAddress group_address = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
private UdpClient udp_client ;
private IPEndPoint remote_end ;


void Start()
{
    // loaded elsewhere
    if (Loader.IsPC)
        StartGameServer();
    else
        StartGameClient();
}

void StartGameServer()
{
    // the Unity3d way to become a server
    NetworkConnectionError init_status = Network.InitializeServer(10, 
server_port, false);
    Debug.Log("status: " + init_status);

    StartCoroutine(StartBroadcast());
}

void StartGameClient()
{
    // multicast receive setup
    remote_end = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, startup_port);
    udp_client = new UdpClient(remote_end);
    udp_client.JoinMulticastGroup(group_address);

    // async callback for multicast
    udp_client.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(ServerLookup), null);

    StartCoroutine(MakeConnection());
}

IEnumerator MakeConnection()
{
    // continues after we get server's address
    while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(server_ip))
        yield return null;

    while (Network.peerType == NetworkPeerType.Disconnected)
    {
        Debug.Log("connecting: " + server_ip + ":" + server_port);

        // the Unity3d way to connect to a server
        NetworkConnectionError error ;
        error = Network.Connect(server_ip, server_port);
        Debug.Log("status: " + error);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (1);
    }
}

/******* broadcast functions *******/
void ServerLookup(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    // receivers package and identifies IP
    var receiveBytes = udp_client.EndReceive(ar, ref remote_end);

    server_ip = remote_end.Address.ToString();
    Debug.Log("Server: " + server_ip);
}

IEnumerator StartBroadcast()
{
    // multicast send setup
    udp_client = new UdpClient();
    udp_client.JoinMulticastGroup(group_address);
    remote_end = new IPEndPoint(group_address, startup_port);

    // sends multicast
    while (true)
    {
        var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("GameServer");
        udp_client.Send(buffer, buffer.Length, remote_end);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds (1);
    }
}
}
```